# How to detect whether browser tab closed or browser window in javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an application which stores the user data in browser's localStorage. So, user can get those data even across browser tabs and windows. But what I want to do is to clear localStorage when user closes the browser window.

I used `beforeunload` function to achieve this but it triggers on tab close also.

So, please help me if there is any way to detect whether browser tab is closed or browser window.

PS: I can't use sessionStorage as it destroys on browser tab close.

Comment: AFAIK not without games; searching the web and SO will provide multiple ideas you can explore.

Answer (score 1):

Use Session Storage in the browser.
Here you don't want to capture the browser tab closing event. The Session Storage data persist for a session of opened tab

```
if (sessionStorage.clickcount) {
    sessionStorage.clickcount = Number(sessionStorage.clickcount) + 1;
} else {
    sessionStorage.clickcount = 1;
}
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "You have clicked the button " +
sessionStorage.clickcount + " time(s) in this session.";
```

I grab those example code from [Here](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp)

**Only Clear when Browser close**

```
localStorage.removeItem(key);
```

Hope this will help you

Comment: I want to clear data on browser window close not on tab close. So, If i use sessionStorage then it'll clear on tab close also which i don't want to do.

Comment: but in your question you mention "whether browser tab is closed or browser window" therefore I post that answer. I will edit my answer. please wait

Comment: sorry for misrepresentation. I just wanted to detect  if it is a browser tab or browser window closed by user. if it is browser window then clear localstorage else retain it. So i am not founding the way for that decision point tab or window. Thanks